# form_for in devise How it works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

rails g devise:views command generated that view

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name))   do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

   <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :username, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

My question is how does it work " form_for(resource, : as=>resource_name, ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resource` is simple a record (or object) - with respect to Devise, it's usually something called `User` or similar.  The rest of the parameters for `form_for` are options, detailed in the [form_for docs.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that both the :email and :username are calling for the email_field, which is a mistake.