# adding more fields to a devise model and using form_for for them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added a few more fields to a devise model, and was trying to create form fields for them in the template. My template looks like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893366/form-for-in-devise-how-it-works).

So what I tried is add a street_number field to the devise model and do

```
<div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :street_number %>
      <%= f.street_number_field :street_number, class: "form-control", required: true %>
</div>
```

Then, I get a error message like

```
undefined method `street_number_field'
```

Is there anything I need to do to make sure street_number is recognized, and I can use the method 'street_number_field' like the default devise fields?

Comment: The error you get is solved with the answer provided by @Padmanaban Gokula. Also in order to be able to update your migrated fields you will need to configure the permitted parameters in application controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no street_number_field in form helpers. Use number_field instead. Check this link for various field types 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :street_number %>
          <%= f.number_field :street_number, class: "form-control", required: true %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this lines into your *aplicaction_controller.rb* file: (replace the fields you need)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:street_number, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:street_number, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end

end
```